# How to add websites dropdown in admin form and grid?

Tags: magento2.2.3

I have created a custom module for this.
but its showing Id in database and grid also, in form only its showing label.

how i can get website label instead of website id in grid. please help.
This is my prepare form code:

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'website',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'website',
                    'label' => __('Associate to Website'),
                    'title' => __('Associate to Website'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => $this->_systemStore->getWebsiteValuesForForm(),

            ]
        );
```

This is a my grid column code:

```
<column name="website">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Website</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
```

Comment: show your listing xml code which you have used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code to listing ui xml

```
<column name="website_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Website ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Websites.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
/**
 * Class ProductActions
 */
class Websites extends Column
{

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;
    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceFormatter;
    /**
     * @var actionUrlBuilder
     */
    protected $actionUrlBuilder;
    /**
     * @var $_storeManager
     */
    protected $_storeManager;


    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceFormatter,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        $this->priceFormatter = $priceFormatter;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $Websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
                $WebsiteName="-";
                foreach ($Websites as $website) {
                    if($website->getId()==$item['website_id']){
                        $WebsiteName = $website->getName();
                    }
                }
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $WebsiteName;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. https://www.screencast.com/t/pYucxm0NvhkD

Comment: change website_id by your field name.

Comment: I want to display attribute options dropdown in admin form and grid, please help me

Comment: I have already Accepted

Comment: Now i am trying to add attribute option dropdown in admin form and grid, please help me on this

Comment: Ask a separate question for it.

Comment: I have posted a separate question for it.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235506/how-we-can-add-product-attribute-options-dropdown-in-admin-form-and-grid?noredirect=1#comment327846_235506

Comment: Grid filter is not working with this. How we can do that?